# python time complexity quick sort algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity, quicksort

```
def partition(A, l, r):
    p = A[l]
    stack = A[l]
    A[l] = A[r]
    A[r] = stack
    s = l

    for i in range(l, r):

        if A[i] <= p:

            stack2 = A[i]
            A[i] = A[s]
            A[s] = stack2
            s += 1

    stack3 = A[s]
    A[s] = A[r]
    A[r] = stack3

    return s

def quicksort(A, l, r):

    if l < r:

        q = partition(A, l, r)
        quicksort(A, l, q - 1)
        quicksort(A, q + 1, r)
    return A
```

I've written "maybe" quicksort algorithm, as I've noticed here the time complexity of partition was O(n) because of the for loop, Also the complexity in quicksort seems to be at least O(n). The question: how is it possible for the entire code to have total time complexity of O(nlogn).

Comment: Where do you get `O(nlogn)`?

Comment: because you have a subtask that is O(n) but you have to do it multiple times.

Comment: Be careful when you express everything about some `n` without saying what `n` is. The recursive calls are made on subarray, whose length are shorter than the original array. The complexity of one call to `partition` is O(n), where n is the length of the subarray partition is called on, not the length of the full array. For instance, if you call partition k times on subarrays of length 1, then the total complexity of those k calls is only O(k).

Comment: @JohnColeman "The average time complexity of quick sort is O(N log(N))" I have read this on this website - iq.opengenus.org.

Comment: But -- you didn't say "average-case complexity" you said "time complexity" full stop -- which as a default means worst-case complexity.

Comment: @Stef tanks, I will define them next time.

Comment: @JohnColeman I've just recognize the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You partition by 2 each level till you get individual elements. Partitioning and comparison what makes the time complexity. You make `n` comparisons in each level and you will be partioning `log2(n)` times.

[image]

In the worst case, your array is already sorted and you will be partitioning n times and still make n comparisons in each level.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your sorting function isn't `O(nlogn)`. In the worst case, you are making `O(n)` recursive calls.

As a simple test:

```
def test(n):
    nums = list(reversed(range(n)))
    return sum(quicksort(nums,0,n-1))
```

Then, for example, `test(1100)` triggers:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Which wouldn't happen if you were calling `partition` just `log(n)` times.

On the other hand,

```
import random

def test2(n):
    nums = list(range(n))
    random.shuffle(nums)
    return sum(quicksort(nums,0,n-1))
```

works well even for calls like `test2(100000)`, so you do have *average case* `O(nlogn)` complexity. This is easy to confirm numerically but difficult to prove. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort for a proof.